# An error occurred (TransactionCanceledException) when calling the TransactWriteItems operation: Transaction cancelled please refer cancellation reason

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb

```
for item in getSort["Items"]:
                    sortkey = item['History']['S']
                    params.append(
                                {
                                    'Update': {
                                        'TableName': 'vanguard-work-item-storage-history-db',
                                         'Key': {
                                            'Id': {
                                            'S': groupid
                                             },
                                            'Category': {
                                                'S': sortkey
                                            }
                                            },
                                        'UpdateExpression': 'set #stat = :val1',
                                        'ExpressionAttributeValues':{
                                            ':val1': {'N':str(int(epoch_value))}
                                        },
                                        'ExpressionAttributeNames': {
                                            '#stat': 'ttl'
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                        )
dynamodb_client.transact_write_items(TransactItems=params)


exception-An error occurred (TransactionCanceledException) when calling the TransactWriteItems operation: Transaction cancelled, please refer cancellation reasons for specific reasons [ValidationError, None, None, 
None, None]
```

How to resolve the above exception. what may be the reason for it. I am adding multiple update items in one array and passing it to the transactwriteitems which is in for loop.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to explain where the error is because the snippet does not seem to be complete.

What I can inferr from the error and the code is that you're appending an item to a list of items, and then trying to save them all in a single transaction.

The error occurs on the first item you're trying to insert. You can notice by looking at the list of errors in the message, the first entry reads `ValidationError`.

```
exception-An error occurred (TransactionCanceledException)
when calling the TransactWriteItems operation: Transaction cancelled,
please refer cancellation reasons for specific reasons 
[ValidationError, None, None, None, None]
```

Look on the first item of your transaction and ensure you're creating the Item following the AWS specs.